# How to End object in BGE after multiple collisions

Tags: game-engine, objects, logic-bricks

I am a student from Malaysia studying animation. This is my final year and I decided to make a 3D game using blender. In my game, I want the object in the BGE to end after taking two or more hits. Because it's too easy to make it die after taking one hit, is there any way to solve this ?

Comment: Please you add more information of what you did already and a screenshot, so people can help you.

Comment: The question title should be much more specific. Such generic questions are not helpful. Please rephrase the question

Comment: I am a Malaysian too.Where did you study?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a new Game Property called lives. Use a collision sensor set to tap, and make a new Property actuator, set mode to add, property to lives, and value to -1. Then add a Property sensor, set property to lives, and value to 0. Connect it to an Edit_Object, end_Object actuator. Set lives to however many lives you want. Hopes this helps